# How can i print the value of a variable to a Textview

Tags: java, android, textview

Here is my code 
(im very beginner)
      Im trying here to print the variable answer on the EditText 
      but i get error which is "cant resolve symbol answer" i dont know how to fix it help please:

```
package com.example.user.test_calculator;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public static double main(String[]args){
    int x , y , answer;
    x = 2;
    y = 3;
    answer = y + x;
    return 0;
}
public void buttonOnClick(View v){
    EditText txtoutput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    txtoutput.setText(String.valueOf(answer));


  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the variable answer outside the method main.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int answer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public static double main(String[]args){
    int x , y;
    x = 2;
    y = 3;
    this.answer = y + x;
    return 0;
}
public void buttonOnClick(View v){
    EditText txtoutput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    txtoutput.setText(String.valueOf(this.answer));


  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `answer` is a local variable which is not available within `buttonOnClick(View v)` method. So define it in the class level.